# iOS 8 AutoLayout: dilemmas with centring UITextView

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitextview, autolayout, universal-storyboard

With all these different screen sizes in iOS 8, I'm having an Auto Layout dilemma trying to **centre** this `UITextView` to display properly on all the different sizes of iPhone.

I've tried using various constraints - but I am still clueless on how to achieve my desired result.
This is where I am ***without applying any constraints***.

[image]

As you may be able to see, I'm using a **universal storyboard** and I am trying to cater for 3.5, 4, 4.7 and 5.5 inch devices.

I recognise that I must apply some sort of constraint or alignment to universally centre the UITextView - my question is ***what should I do to achieve this?***

**Ultimately**, is there a method that I can employ for my storyboard content to be scaled proportionally on all devices, avoiding this issue of variated alignment on different screen sizes? I'm having a similar problem on my other `UIViewControllers`, to display `UIKit`elements in proportion to as seen on the storyboard. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you want the text view centred with a fixed width and height? Or do you want the size to change?

Comment: Ideally, I would want it to change in proportion to the device's screen size alongside the text size, but first I would like to get the alignment right on all devices before implementing those additions.

Comment: Simply add constraints setting the distance from the left, right, top and bottom margins

Comment: @Paulw11 That works to a certain extent, how would I go about aligning the UITextView to the centre of each, respective device screen size?

Comment: Well, if you have equal space to the margins, left and right, and no width constraint then it will be centred.  If you have set a width then you can align the the item using the Editor->align->Horizontal center in container menu item